# Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: angularjs, file, upload

I am trying to implement the functionality to upload multiple files and trying  mail those files to target user using Spring controller. Front end I am using Angular Js.

In bean I declared variable as followes.

private MultipartFile fileList;

And in Controller the method signature is ...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reachUs/reason", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String processIssue(
    @RequestBody ReachUsBean reachUsBean,
    final HttpSession session) {...}
```

## Angular Js:

```
ReachIssues = $resource(appPath + '/reachUs/reason.do', null, {
    'save' : {
        method : 'POST',
        timeout : 30000,
        url : appPath+ '/reachtUs/reason.do',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
                            return data;
                                     }}
                            }),

$scope.formData = {
    contactEmail : $scope.user.cust.email,
    preferModeOfContact : $scope.contactMethod,
    fileList :      $scope.selectedFiles[0]
};
```

While doing this getting following exception. I google it for fix this, but no luck.

***org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported***

Please do help.